# In-game dialogues

Tags: portal-2

Is there any tutorials or even communities which are devoted to in-game dialogues extraction (text + audio)? I've managed to do this for Portal 2, for instance. But there's a plenty of games to operate on. :)

The main purpose is learning the language (yes, I'm not native english speaking person :) )

UPD: I mention extraction of audio and extraction of the corresponding text subtitles. Not converting the audio to text.

Comment: Why the down-vote? Seems like a halfway-decent question. Although, I think it would maybe fit better on gamedev?

Comment: It would be a much better fit onto gamedev.

Comment: So, you just want to listen to the audio without playing the game as a language learning mechanism?

Comment: Exactly! And read the corresponding text which is supposed to be shown as subtitles.

Answer (score 1):

Some resources include [youtube](http://www.youtube.com) by searching for [game name] quotes. Also [Game Faqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com) usually has FAQs devoted to converting the speech into text.

Of course you could always just play the game.

Comment: You can think of me as of pervert but instead of wasting my time for playing I'd rather watch the video walkthrough on gameanyone.com :)

Comment: @igorp1024 - Given that you mentioned you're trying to learn English, I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that "pervert" isn't the word you intended. I'd suggest "strange" instead. "Pervert" has a much, *much* more negative connotation.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: That was a joke :) I can tell the difference between "strange" and "pervert". Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I have to answer my question by myself.

The translators communities members are interested in resources extraction (translation and repacking). So, at the moment I see the only way to extract the audio+subtitles. You need to use [Dragon UnPACKer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dragonunpacker/) or [GCFScape](http://nemesis.thewavelength.net/index.php?p=25) in order to extract all resources. Then find there the resources you are interested in.

That's it.